# Payment gateway in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to determine a user is paid for the product and now he is authorised to use the product?

Answer (score 1):

Just store the data into the list using cursor and pass that list to the adapter. For putting the data into list refer the following code :

```
 List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            myList.add(cursor.getString(0));

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [SimpleCursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)

```
String[] from = {"column"};
int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, 
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
          cursor, 
          from, 
          to, 
          0);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```